# SQL Join Tables - 2nd newest entry to related main entry in other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-server-2000

following abstract scenario. I have 2 tables. One is containing "posts" and the other "comments"
If you create a new "post", there is also a new "comment" added of type "initial". Whenever you now add a real comment, it gets the postID and a type like "picture","text", "movie" ...

I now need to get one table showing the initial posts date and the first "real" comment. I want to know how long it took until the first comment was written.

```
SELECT post.ID,post.Title,post.Author,post.CreateDate,
comment.Type,comment.Text,comment.CreateDate
FROM Posts as post
INNER JOIN Comments as comments on post.ID = comment.PostID
```

That gives me the Post Info for the amount of comments.
Now I want to just have the very first "real" comment date standing next to the createDate of the post ( where comment.Type != 'initial')

Don't know how to do that. Could someone help me in this case?
It should be possible to run it also on MS SQL 2000...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT post.ID,max(post.Title),max(post.Author),min(post.CreateDate),
min(comment.CreateDate),
datediff(mi,min(post.CreateDate),min(comment.CreateDate)) as 'first comment in minutes'
FROM Posts as post
INNER JOIN Comments as comments on post.ID = comment.PostID
where  comment.Type != 'initial'
group by post.id
```

Comment: This works great! Thank you. If you have the time, could you plese add a short explanation?

Comment: I'm glad it helps. Take a look at this for Aggregate Funcions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx

Comment: I used `min(comment.CreateDate)` to determine first real comment after filtering `where  comment.Type != 'initial'`